# Can someone explain how to input function in auditorium?

Tags: input, numbers, tags, helper, six

this is my problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpNKd.png)

i tried hours but i can't do it
Print("Help me i cant do it")
Print("Help me i cant do it")

Print("Help me i cant do it")

Print("Help me i cant do it")

Print("Help me i cant do it")

Print("Help me i cant do it")

Print("Help me i cant do it")

Print("Help me i cant do it")

Print("Help me i cant do it")

Print("Help me i cant do it")

Print("Help me i cant do it")

Print("Help me i cant do it")

Comment: Putting garbage in your question to get around the length restriction is simply abuse of the website.

Answer (score -1):

num1=input("enter first number:")

num2=input("enter second number:")

sum=float(num1)+float(num2)

print(sum)